# vxlist volume and vxlist disk stuck on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, lvm

On Solaris 10 i have installed symantec storage foundation
for lvm.
Enable all daemons,create volumes and groups ok
but if i want to see the size of disk and volumes
with

```
vxlist volume
```

or

```
vxlist disk
```

It stuck freeze,and i get nothing
The output must be like this as i see in this [docs](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/displaying-volume-and-disk-sizes-human-friendly-format-mb-gb-tb-volume-manager-vxvm)

```
[root@server101 ~]# vxlist disk

TY   DEVICE         DISK   DISKGROUP        SIZE      FREE STATUS

disk ibm_shark0_0   d0     sharedg1      989.87m   489.87m imported

disk ibm_shark0_1   -      -                   -         - uninitialized

disk ibm_shark0_9   d9     datadg          2.86t     1.86t imported

disk sda            -      -                   -         - uninitialized


[root@server101 ~]# vxlist volume

TY   VOLUME     DISKGROUP        SIZE STATUS    LAYOUT   LINKAGE

vol  cfs1       sharedg1      500.00m healthy   concat   -

vol  testvol1   datadg          1.00t healthy   concat   -
```

Using truss i see

```
open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY)          = 4
ioctl(4, TIOCGSID, 0x080476E0)          = 0
getsid(0)                   = 1391
ioctl(4, TIOCGPGRP, 0x080476F8)         = 0
getpgrp()                   = 15173
so_socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, "", SOV_DEFAULT) = 5
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, 0x00000001)           = 0
setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, 0x08047248, 4, SOV_DEFAULT) = 0
setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, 0x08047248, 4, SOV_DEFAULT) = 0
connect(5, 0x080471D6, 34, SOV_DEFAULT)     = 0
send(5, " < ? x m l   v e r s i o".., 2465, 0)  = 2465
pollsys(0x08047360, 1, 0x080473E8, 0x00000000) (sleeping...)
```

Comment: Anything in `/var/adm/messages` ?  Tried a `vxdctl enable` ?

Comment: From `so_socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, "", SOV_DEFAULT) = 5` and `send(5, " < ? x m l   v e r s i o".., 2465, 0)  = 2465`, it looks like it's sending something over a Unix socket and waiting for a reply.  Offhand I'd say that whatever daemon is supposed to be listening to the other end of that Unix socket isn't running.  Post the output of a `truss -vall ...`.  That will provide some more data that might be useful.

Comment: is vxconfigd running?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the vxconfigd? If yes, I'm sorry, but the only way to resolve the vxconfigd in stuck mode is a reboot...

Comment: Very bad thing,i prefer the other unix lvm like hpux lvm,linux lvm,aix lvm,if you put the comment as asnwer i can vote it